# What is meant by "obfuscate by pretending"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I came accross the following sentence:

"Politicians **obfuscate by pretending** that the world would be the same if it weren't for the Cold War."

What is the meaning of obfuscate by pretending and how does it relate to the rest of the sentence?

The way I understood it: politicans are aware that the world would not be the same if it weren't for the Cold War, but are (due to unknown or suspected reasons) not willing to admit this and therefore pretend otherwise.

Comment: You understood it right. They are just trying to confuse others.

Comment: I had upvoted vickyace's comment, but I would add that more than mere confusion, obfuscate also contains a dash of concealment (of the truth) and a splash of misdirection.

Comment: When you ask about 'obfuscate by pretending,' you are leaving out the setting of the sentence.  Turned around, it means: "When they pretend that the world would be the same if it weren't for the Cold War, politicians who say that (or promote that pretense) are deliberately obfuscating for their own agenda (that the Cold War was a good thing)." To push their idea, they hide what they don't want you to notice and build up what they want you to see.

Answer (score 1):

***[Obfuscate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obfuscate)*** in the sentence is used with the connotation of:

> to make obscure or unclear:
>   - *to obfuscate a problem with extraneous information.*

(Dictionary.com)

Usage:

> - Although the verb [obfuscate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/obfuscate) can be used in any case where something is darkened, less clear, or more obscure, ***it is most frequently used in reference to things like ideas, facts, issues, or the truth***.
> - ***The usual implied meaning is that this obfuscation is done deliberately*** . ***Politicians often obfuscate the truth about the issues to win support for their positions so they can win elections.***

(Vocabulary.com)